# How to add a custom property or method to a promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Regular promises have the beloved `.then()` and `.catch()` functions.

When `promising` to retrieve an object that itself has properties that return promises we find chains of promises such as the following:

```
require("clientside-view-loader")
    .then((view)=>
        return view.load("clientside-view-modal-login_signup");
    })
    .then((compiler)=>{
        return compiler.generate()
    })
    .then((modal)=>{
        document.body.appendChild(modal);
        modal.show("login");
    })
```

This is UGLY!

How can we modify a promise to attach a custom property so that we can convert the above into the following?

```
require("clientside-view-loader")
    .load("clientside-view-modal-login_signup")
    .generate()
    .then((modal)=>{
        document.body.appendChild(modal);
        modal.show("login");
    })
```

*note, these examples use the [`clientside-require`](https://npmjs.com/package/clientside-require) `require` and not the `nodejs` `require`*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can we modify a promise to attach a custom property so that we can convert the above into the following?

You don't modify promises at all. You just implement the builder pattern for the above promise chain.

```
class ClientSideViewLoader {
  constructor(p = Promise.resolve()) {
    this.promise = p;
  }
  static init() {
    return new this(require("clientside-view-loader"));
  }
  load(x) {
    return new this.constructor(this.promise.then(view =>
      view.load(x)
    ));
  }
  generate() {
    return new this.constructor(this.promise.then(compiler => 
      compiler.generate()
    ));
  }
  then(...args) {
    return this.promise.then(...args);
  }
}

ClientSideViewLoader.init()
.load("clientside-view-modal-login_signup")
.generate()
.then(modal => {
  document.body.appendChild(modal);
  modal.show("login");
})
```

No need to do anything complicated like subclassing `Promise`. If you want, you can also dynamically generate all these methods.

> This is UGLY!

Well, if you were looking for beautiful promise code, you would simply use modern `async`/`await` syntax instead of `then` callbacks:

```
const view = await require("clientside-view-loader");
const compiler = await view.load("clientside-view-modal-login_signup");
const modal = await compiler.generate();
document.body.appendChild(modal);
modal.show("login");
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can "resolve" this builder class `ClientSideViewLoader` from a promise? e.g., `require("clientside-view-loader")` resolves `ClientSideViewLoader.init()`? 

My problem is that the `load` and `generate` methods are defined asynchronously.

Comment: @UladKasach Of course you can make a module that directly returns a builder instance. But I'm not sure what you mean by "asynchronously" - no, the builder methods must be defined from the get go, otherwise the builder calls would need to be placed inside a promise chain - quite pointless.

Comment: I've clarified my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812252/how-to-add-properties-to-a-promise-asynchronously,  since i was too general in the original question on this thread. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Your initial code can be made shorter and more readable simply by using different syntax for your [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). These two rules of arrow function syntax are relevant:

- parentheses are optional around the only argument of single-argument functions
- single-statement functions that return a value can have the `{}` and the `return` removed

Thus, you could write your code like this, with the short form `view => …` instead of `(view) => { return …; }`:

```js
require("clientside-view-loader")
    .then(view => view.load("clientside-view-modal-login_signup"))
    .then(compiler => compiler.generate())
    .then(modal => {
        document.body.appendChild(modal);
        modal.show("login");
    });
```

Comment: If arrow functions need to return an object literal however you need to use parentheses: `x=>({someProp:x})`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the properties you wish to add in advance you can simply append a property to the promise like you would any other object:

```
view_loader.load = function(path){
    return this.then((view_loader)=>{
        return view_loader.load(path)
    })
}
view_loader.load(...) // now works!
```

Here's a function that does this for a dynamic set of properties:

```
function modify_orig_promise(original_promise, properties_to_append){
    var blacklist = ["then", "catch", "spread"];
    var function_keys = Object.keys(properties_to_append);
    for(var i = 0; i < function_keys.length; i++){
        var function_key = function_keys[i];
        if(blacklist.indexOf(function_key) > -1) {
            console.warn("properties_to_append in require(__, {functions : {} }) included a blacklisted function name : `"+key+"`. skipping this property.")
        } else {
            var requested_function = properties_to_append[function_key];
            original_promise[function_key] = requested_function; // append the function to the promise
        }
    }
    return original_promise;
}
```

Then

```
var properties_to_append = {
    load : function(path){
        return this.then((view_loader)=>{ return view_loader.load(path)}) 
    }
}
modified_require = modify_orig_promise(require("clientside-view-loader"), properties_to_append);
modified_require.load("clientside-view-modal-login_signup") // Works
```

---

If you dont know the properties in advance (e.g., the properties are determined from a promise) you'll need to use a proxy that waits until that promise resolves to respond. This is answered here: [How to add properties to a promise asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812252/how-to-add-properties-to-a-promise-asynchronously)